# Email Layout - Right to Left

Tags: email, layout

I've been trying to figure out how to get the copy side and the image side to switch places. I was using https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/layout-manipulation/ for reference and I get the concept, I just can't make it happen.

[image]

[image]

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" align="center" border="0" class="container">

<tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" valign="center" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#707249">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><img src="http://www.leejofa.com/emails/images/baker-logo.png" max-width="200px" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 125% 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF">Larkhill</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="desktop">
                                    <td class="desktop">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="http://search.leejofa.com/itembrowser.aspx?action=attributes&ItemType=WallCovering&resetCrumbs=true&Brand=G%20P%20%26%20J%20Baker&WallCovering%20Collection=Larkhill&offset=0?utm_source=viewcollection&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=Farrow-Ball-Exit-March-2017" style="font:normal 100% 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF">SEARCH COLLECTION <strong style="font:normal 75% Arial, sans-serif">&#9658;</strong></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" class="mobile2"><a href="http://search.leejofa.com/itembrowser.aspx?action=attributes&ItemType=WallCovering&resetCrumbs=true&Brand=G%20P%20%26%20J%20Baker&WallCovering%20Collection=Larkhill&offset=0?utm_source=viewcollection&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=Farrow-Ball-Exit-March-2017"><img src="http://www.leejofa.com/emails/images/larkhill.jpg" alt="Furness Weaves" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="60%" class="mobile2"><a href="http://search.leejofa.com/itembrowser.aspx?action=attributes&ItemType=WallCovering&resetCrumbs=true&Brand=Baker%20Lifestyles&Collection=Denbury&offset=0?utm_source=viewcollection&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=Farrow-Ball-Exit-March-2017"><img src="http://www.leejofa.com/emails/images/denbury.jpg" alt="Furness Weaves" /></a></td>
                        <td width="40%" valign="center" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#007DB1">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><img src="http://www.leejofa.com/emails/images/lifestyle-logo.png" max-width="200px" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 125% 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF">Denbury</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="desktop">
                                    <td class="desktop">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="http://search.leejofa.com/itembrowser.aspx?action=attributes&ItemType=WallCovering&resetCrumbs=true&Brand=Baker%20Lifestyles&Collection=Denbury&offset=0?utm_source=viewcollection&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=Farrow-Ball-Exit-March-2017" style="font:normal 100% 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF">SEARCH COLLECTION <strong style="font:normal 75% Arial, sans-serif">&#9658;</strong></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Mobile view added. I'm trying to make the first copy and image look like the second set.

Comment: do you want the text to appear on the left and image right like the 2nd set?

Comment: No, it's more about the mobile view. When it's say 480px, the text on the left should go below the image. See second image in blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use direction in style tag for this:

```
style="direction:rtl" and style="direction:rtl"
```

I took you code and 
1. Removed the last row (place it as separate table)
2. Added the direction styles to the tables and
3. Added a media query so you can test it

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
table[class].Colms td{display:inline-block; width:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" align="center" border="0" class="container">
    
    <tr>
    <td align="center">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%" style="direction: rtl;" class="Colms">
    <tr>
    
    <td width="60%" class="mobile2" style="direction:ltr"><a href="http://search.leejofa.com/itembrowser.aspx?action=attributes&ItemType=WallCovering&resetCrumbs=true&Brand=G%20P%20%26%20J%20Baker&WallCovering%20Collection=Larkhill&offset=0?utm_source=viewcollection&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=Farrow-Ball-Exit-March-2017"><img src="http://www.leejofa.com/emails/images/larkhill.jpg" alt="Furness Weaves" /></a></td>
    <td width="40%" valign="center" align="center" class="mobile2" bgcolor="#707249" style="direction:ltr">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
     <tr>
      <td align="center"><img src="http://www.leejofa.com/emails/images/baker-logo.png" max-width="200px" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 125% 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF">Larkhill</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="desktop">
      <td class="desktop">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center"><a href="http://search.leejofa.com/itembrowser.aspx?action=attributes&ItemType=WallCovering&resetCrumbs=true&Brand=G%20P%20%26%20J%20Baker&WallCovering%20Collection=Larkhill&offset=0?utm_source=viewcollection&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=Farrow-Ball-Exit-March-2017" style="font:normal 100% 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF">SEARCH COLLECTION <strong style="font:normal 75% Arial, sans-serif">&#9658;</strong></a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

The directions are for text: ltr (left-to-right) and rlt(right-to-left). The table has rtl and each of the td's have ltr. You can run the snippets above, do full screen and see it work.

Cheers

Comment: Awesome, it worked!. Any advice for someone new to email design, like myself?

Comment: Visualise the design and think about the limitations before designing. It will save a lot of hair pulling. Email has it fun moments and really annoying ones.